# Data Frame redesign : merge 2 row in one single row - and rename by value

Tags: r

I am new to R. I did a lot of research and test in order to find an elegant answer to this question. I have try reshape, t, melt, etc. I am also struggling with the name of the variables. 
I am stuck with a data frame like this.  We have a time when the question is asked (before Question 1), then on the second line we have a time that the answer was recorded.

```
    Time            Logs
    446.6204    Question1
    452.7516    4
    452.7516    Question2
    458.1999    3
    458.1999    Question3
    460.2342    5
```

I would like to have everything on one line and name the variable with the value in "Logs".  Luck for me the pattern is constant so working with slicing can be good.

```
Respondent TimeQ1   Question1   TimeA1  TimeQ2  Question2   TimeA2  TimeQ3  Question3   TimeA3
Respondent1 446.6204    4   452.7516    452.7516    3   458.1999    458.1999    5   460.2342
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is not a code-generation service. What R code have you tried so far and what isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a column for respondents, and added data for multiple respondents. Here is the example dataset:

```
DF <- structure(list(Respondent = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Respondent 1", 
"Respondent 2", "Respondent 3"), class = "factor"), Time = c(446.6204, 
452.7516, 452.7516, 458.1999, 458.1999, 460.2342, 535.94448, 
543.30192, 543.30192, 549.83988, 549.83988, 552.28104, 443.2204, 
449.3516, 449.3516, 454.7999, 454.7999, 456.8342), Logs = structure(c(6L, 
4L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 
5L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "Question1", "Question2", 
"Question3"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Respondent", "Time", 
"Logs"), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")
```

I don't think having the data all on one line is your best option.  If you have a large number of questions then you're line is going to be insanely long.

Here is the format I suggested earlier (which I still think is better):

```
 newDF <- data.frame(respondent = DF$Respondent[grep("Question", DF$Logs)],
                question = as.character(DF$Logs[grep("Question", DF$Logs)]),
                questionTime = DF$Time[grep("Question", DF$Logs)],
                responseValue = DF$Logs[-grep("Question", DF$Logs)],
                responseTime = DF$Time[-grep("Question", DF$Logs)])
newDF

 #   respondent  question questionTime responseValue responseTime
 # Respondent 1 Question1     446.6204             4     452.7516
 # Respondent 1 Question2     452.7516             3     458.1999
 # Respondent 1 Question3     458.1999             5     460.2342
 # Respondent 2 Question1     535.9445             5     543.3019
 # Respondent 2 Question2     543.3019             2     549.8399
 # Respondent 2 Question3     549.8399             3     552.2810
 # Respondent 3 Question1     443.2204             1     449.3516
 # Respondent 3 Question2     449.3516             4     454.7999
 # Respondent 3 Question3     454.7999             5     456.8342
```

## Edit

Based on the fact that there is an additional column for the respondent you can use something like `dcast` to put the data from my table above into what you're looking for. Here are the steps:

```
 qTime <- dcast(newDF, respondent ~ question, value.var = "questionTime")
names(qTime)[2:length(names(qTime))] <- paste0("TimeQ", seq(1,length(names(qTime))-1,1) )

rValue <- dcast(newDF, respondent ~ question, value.var = "responseValue")

rTime <- dcast(newDF, respondent ~ question, value.var = "responseTime")
names(rTime)[2:length(names(rTime))] <- paste0("TimeA", seq(1,length(names(rTime))-1,1) )

finalDF <- cbind(qTime, rValue[,-1], rTime[,-1])

finalDF

#     respondent   TimeQ1   TimeQ2   TimeQ3 Question1 Question2 Question3   TimeA1   TimeA2   TimeA3
#   Respondent 1 446.6204 452.7516 458.1999         4         3         5 452.7516 458.1999 460.2342
#   Respondent 2 535.9445 543.3019 549.8399         5         2         3 543.3019 549.8399 552.2810
#   Respondent 3 443.2204 449.3516 454.7999         1         4         5 449.3516 454.7999 456.8342
```

You'll have to fiddle with the column order if you really want, but in general this should do it.

Comment: thanks for your great answer mrp. I will continue working on a solution that would put everything into one line.  You see, I must have one line for every respondent. I think that aggregate might do it. Thanks again. :-)

Comment: @MartinTavarez Does every respondent answer all the same questions?

Comment: Yes, the questionnaire ask them to answer all the same questions.

Comment: @MartinTavarez so then you should also have another column with Respondent ID number? ie, Respondent 1, Respondent 2, Respondent 3, etc..?

Comment: @MartinTavarez I've edited my response to produce what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks so much! That's awesome! :-)